# Branches in TFS are physical or Virtual?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

We have Branched our TFS based code and and when got latest version it created a separate physical directory on our machine unlike git where we can have only one copy at a time and can switch the branches? 
Creating a separate physical directory is just like creating a separate project, i am confused about TFS branching concept. Is it something central on server or it is creating separate directory on server too?

Comment: A branch is just a bunch of links to the original files, until you start committing changes. How will this answer resolve your confusion? What _exactly_ do you want to know?

Comment: On my machine  three directories have been created,one for each branch , isn't the same if i create three projects with same code? it is now occupying space of three projects. i have worked with GitHub branches previously and there we have only one active branch on local machine.

Comment: TFS VC stores code in a SQL server DB, behind the scenes when you create a new branch it's just a pointer to the original and then diffs are generated when you check in. I wouldn't worry too much about the server implementation, even if you're the DBA responsible for the TFS DB, it should be a black box. Locally however the branches manifest themselves as separate folders on your file system so you don't switch branches in the same way as you would in Git, you just edit the files in the appropriate local directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The branches in Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) are separate "directories" on the server also; the branch folder "keeps" only the differences from the parent folder so the size of the stored data is far less than the double of the parent size. 
And yes you'll have two different folders for the same project on your local workspace; three's no concept of active branch.